# PHP, MySQL, IIS7.5 and FALSE

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, iis-7.5

I have a Laravel (3) website (so PHP & MySQL) on an IIS7.5 box - it's not good, but can't be changed at this stage (someone ordered the wrong OS on the server!)...

One of the queries is setting a TinyInt (1) field to True or False. This works on the development Apache box fine - but on the IIS, I get an 'Incorrect integer value' message.

I'm guessing that PHP on Apache 'knows' that False is zero, but is there any way to tell PHP that False is zero and True is 1?

Thanks

Comment: cast to integer $something = (int) $something;

Comment: I guess you mean `false` and `true` rather than `False` and `True`.